# IntelliSense not finding methods

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm working in Asp.net and IntelliSense isn't finding the methods in app code. It executes the code well without any issue at run time, but I'm not able to see the method names while coding. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: switch to a web application project type rather than a web site project type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telesense, is that like telekinesis or teleportation?  Perhaps you have an aura around your computer that keeps it from accessing the programming force to determine the methods.  Oh, you mean **intellisense**.  `:-)`

Try rebuilding your web site.  Check to make sure the files are set to "Compile" not "Content". If that doesn't work, try resetting your VS settings:

```
 devenv /resetSettings
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the time honoured methods of fixing this is to delete the existing intellisense file with the solution closed, and re-open it again to get Visual Studio to rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was fixed after restarting Visual Studio.