# Function definitions missing from intellisense in Visual Studio C++ 2005-2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, intellisense

The following problem plagues one of my projects for a long time:

**Some function definitions (from .cpp files) are excluded/hidden from intellisense!**

It is not possible to "**Goto Definition**" for those functions, nor are the listed in the **Navigation Bar**.

The functions do appear in the autocompletion list, though. The problem is for .cpp files only, the .h files are parsed fine. 'Goto Declaration' works, too.

This is the same since 2005, with every new version, I was hoping for a fix, but it does not seem to be regognized as a bug by anyone else.

**UPDATE:**
I have tracked this down to the following: All functions containing a certain macro are not recognized by intellisense. The original macro was

```
#define forlist(x,list) for( auto x= list.begin(); x.valid(); ++x)
```

but you can also use the simplified test case

```
#define fortest(x)  for( auto x= 1; x< 2; ++x)

void myclass::TestFN()
{
    fortest( g )
    {
        g;
    }
}
```

Next step would be to find a workaround (or try to go through micrsoft bug reporting).

Please don't rant too much about this macro. This is existing code of a list implementation which I am not able to change. I could just NOT use the macro, but I still think this is a VS bug.

One funny thing is, that the following (really *****ic macro) works fine:

```
#define fortest(x)  for( auto x= 1; x< 2; ++x) {

void myclass::TestFN()
{
    fortest( g )
        g;
    }
}
```

Could it be that intellisense treats case 1 as an illegal local function definition? 
(see http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/781121/c-intellisense-mistakes-loop-expression-for-function-definition)

The following work fine, too

```
#define fortest(x)  for( auto x= 1; x< 2; ++x)

void myclass::TestFN()
{
    fortest( g )
        g;
}
```

Comment: Did you try the fixes mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500674/intellisense-not-finding-methods ?

Comment: 1. The 'fix' you mention consist in restarting/cleaning/rebuilding intellisense. I have done that about 2300 times in the last years and it did not help ;o)


 2. I do not want to reset ALL my VS settings. It cannot be a VS setting problem anyway, because other projects work fine.

Comment: So you have one project where everything works and another where intellisense happens to miss some functions and you're sure that it is a bug or something and not some kind of project corruption? Well then I won't ask you whether you rebuilt the project from scratch, since you probably did that about 1700 times already.

Comment: You are asking for help but not the kind of help that won't help you. You want to know this specific thing that solves your problem, right?

Comment: @Pixelchemist What kinds of Project corruption could occur?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi There is maybe 1 in 10.000 programmers having the same issue and probably 1 out of 100 of them has been smart enough to solve it. So I am prepared to wait ...

Comment: see this related post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457724/why-might-the-q-foreach-macro-break-vs2010-intellisense

Comment: also see this bug report:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/781121/c-intellisense-mistakes-loop-expression-for-function-definition

Comment: Yet another link describing it is http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/588308/vs2010-c-intellisense-treats-preprocessor-macros-as-functions

Comment: Can also happen when using uniform initialization on dereferenced pointers (different cause, same effect): https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1817908

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As usual, interest in my question ebbed up after a couple of hours, so I had to figure it out by myself...

We just have to use the concept of `cpp.hint` files.

Basically you have to put the troublesome macros into a file named `cpp.hint` and put that file in your solution directory (which did not work for me)
OR in a parent-directory where your code files reside in. (worked for me)

In that file we just put the troublesome macros WITHOUT right-hand-side, so e.g.:

```
#define forlist(x,list)
```

> **NOTE**: Your must reset IntelliSense cache for use new data from changed `cpp.hint` file. You should:
>
> - delete `ipch` folder (usually placed in Solution folder).
> - delete all *.sdf files in Solution folder.
> - delete all *.VC.db files in Solution folder or in `ipch` folder.

For more advanced macros (like having 'start' and 'end' macros for code blocks), there are some other tricks.

The original link is:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997977.aspx

The reason for the trouble is that Intellisense performance would (potentially) decrease dramatically if it had to parse all macros in a project, so it only parses those given explicitly in 'cpp.hint'.

Comment: I just found, that I have to make some change to every .cpp file (e.g. adding a new line) for the effect to kick in. The fix seemingly is not automatically applied.

Comment: thanks man you opened my eyes! however for me it worked like this: copy the macros you want with all the definitions and put the cpp.init file in the main directory where the solution is!