# 'for' macro is causing function definition to be not found by Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

I'm experiencing a weird issue with Visual Studio 2015. Whenever I use the macro below the function I'm using it in becomes undefined to Visual Studio. Worth to mention that this is only a visual issue and doesn't cause any problems while compiling. Also worth to mention that this is only happening when I use a variable as the max value. Here's the macro:

```
#define fiz(MAX_VALUE) for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (MAX_VALUE); i++)

void functionFoo() 
{
    unsigned int max_val = 10;
    fiz(max_val) { // if I use 10 here I don't experience the same issue
        /* do stuff */
    }
}
```

Edit:
So my question is, did anyone else experience same/similar issue and if they were able to fix it?
Edit2: 
Upon further searching I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480235/function-definitions-missing-from-intellisense-in-visual-studio-c-2005-2013). Apparently this issue(or according to the article a performance related design choice) has been existing since Visual Studio 2005. Following the solution in that link has fixed the problem.

Comment: create `i`  before the loop and initialize it in the loop

Comment: @Jguillot Thanks for the quick reply. Still experiencing the same issue regardless of where I declare `i`

Comment: What does the compilator say?

Comment: There're no issues with compiling so it doesn't say anything. It's a visual bug which is causing my function declarations to be displayed as undefined.

Comment: What is the question?  You forgot to ask one.

Comment: My bad. Edited the question.

Comment: With "undefined" you mean undefined in the compiled executable or invisible in your IDE? The later I can believe. Macros that disrupt the usual lexical interpretation of code are not easy to deal with in an IDE.

Comment: I mean the later. The IDE simply says that there's no definition avaliable for the function and gives me the option to create a new one identical to one I have with said macro.

Answer (score 0):

MAX_VALUE is an existing definition, so your macro get 'macrod' by replacing the MAX_VALUE with a large integer number.

Then, the line in your code does not match the macro definition, and cannot be replaced.

Try using another word (*any* other) than MAX_VALUE.

Comment: Hi. Sadly changing the parameter name didn't solve the issue(tried with `MYMAXVAL`)